# achartengine - Chart line doesn't sit on the coloured region if a point goes above the visible region

Tags: java, android, achartengine, renderer, linegraph

I have made a simple Line graph with the lower region coloured.

```
    FillOutsideLine fill = new FillOutsideLine(FillOutsideLine.Type.BOUNDS_ALL);
    fill.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.graph_green));
    renderer.addFillOutsideLine(fill);
```

It's working fine if the data points remain in the visible region.

As soon as a point goes beyond/above the visible region - **the line over the coloured region jumps.**

[image: the line doesn't sit on the colored region on zoom if the point goes beyond the visible region]

I'm guessing it's the problem of the library.

Anyone else faced this issue and is there any workaround to solve this problem?

Comment: I have also got this issue... have any solutions??

Comment: No, I was not able to solve this..Just make sure that you limit the zoom/pan as soon as data point tries to go beyond visible region.

Comment: ok, thanks for your suggestion. and i have another issue that sometimes line doesnt shows on the graph a chartengine   have you any solutions? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23244346/sometimes-line-doesnt-shows-on-the-graph-a-chartengine

Comment: You can turn Hardware acceleration off..Updated the question with an answer ..Thanks